# 9-patch background renders with artifacts and cropping

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I'm using a 9-patch file for a button background, and while the draw9patch tool validates the file, in Android Studio it renders with artifacts and cropping. I'm not sure if this is a bug in Android Studio or a mistake in my 9-patch.  Here is the code for the button, if it helps.

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_panel_share_icon_default"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/view_type_button_background_left_default"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
```

Here's my 9-patch:

[image: 9-patch file]

this is what I think it should look like on the button:

[image]

but this is what I'm actually getting ( the bottom line is a 26% transparency over a dark background ):

[image]

you can see that there is an errant black line on the left, and the black line that should be on the right is apparently cropped.

Update:

Here is the actual 9-patch file, what I posted earlier was a screen shot of the file, for the sake of seeing the fine details.

[image]

Update2:

Ok, I figured out how to make it display correctly, but I still don't understand the reason for the initial failure.  I realized that if I place the top marker next to the off-black line that is part of the 9-patch content, it fails; however, if i move it 1 pixel to the left it renders correctly.

Works:
[image]

Fails:
[image]

Here is the new 9-patch and a screenshot of the successful rendering:

[image]

[image]

Update 3:

I just recreated the 9-patch using the draw9patch tool and the behavior is the same.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer on what's causing this behavior.

Comment: Did you create the 9patch file from draw9patch tool or from some gfx asset creation tool like Photoshop? All kinds of wacky behavior would show up if the 9patch files are not saved by draw9patch.

Comment: Unfortunately I received these assets from a design studio, so I'm not sure how they made them.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the 9patch png you provide, the following image is the left black dot of your png, which is not correct. The borders of the 9patch pngs should be only 1 pixel width, and could only use black as its color, which is (0, 0, 0).

Look [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for more information.

[image]

Comment: That wasn't the actual 9-patch file, but a screen shot of the file.  I wanted it to be large enough to see.  I will add the original file to my post.

Comment: It's really wired, sorry cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have face the problem similar to your once.

I guess you place the nine patch image in folder with lower resolution than device.

When device try to get the image it need to scale the image up and your top marker is right at the "border" which is the gradient area [image].

This can result in unpredictable image after scale.

Comment: device was xhdpi, and 9-patch was in drawable/xhdpi folder.

Comment: That's so wired, really.

Answer (score 0):

You make it too high.

Try to make it like i post.

[image]

Comment: could you post a larger picture? I can't make out the details.

Comment: why do you need a larger picture? 9-patch is for scale~

Comment: Never mind, I downloaded it and zoomed in.  But this 9-patch looks nothing like mine, you have gradients on the left, and you removed the black line and gradient on the bottom.  Furthermore I don't understand what you mean by "you make it too high."

Comment: i just cut top part of you original 9-patch to make mine. i mean, 9-path is for scale, so why your original 9-patch's heigh if more than 800px? you just need a small picture that have gradients around.

Comment: The image you downloaded wasn't the original 9-patch but a screenshot of the original, I updated my post. The original is 82 pixels in height wich for xhdpi would be 40dp after you remove the 2 pixels on the border.  It needs to be this height because there is a slight gradient from top to bottom.  The amount of expansion in the height will be minimal across devices, but the button is intended to be uniform horizontally.

Comment: which folder did you put your 9-patch

Comment: I put it in drawable/xhdpi

Answer (score 0):

Do you use

> ...\Android\android-sdk\tools\draw9patch.bat

to draw your image? It's really helpful and show preliminary result.